# Shorter Alternative to ternary to generate empty string if nil?

Tags: swift, null, conditional-operator

I have a parameter of Type `Double?`.
When this parameter is `nil`, I want to have an empty string.

I can use `if (variable == nil) ? "" : String(variable!)` but is there a shorter alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a simple way to simplify your code. An idea is to create a Double extension like this:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Double {
    var asString: String {
        self == nil ? "" : String(self!)
    }
}
```

And then instead of that if condition you just use:

```
variable.asString
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) and the nil-coalescing operator [`??`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID72) you can do

```
var variable: Double? = 1.0
let string = variable.map { String($0) } ?? ""
```

The closure is called (and the string returned) if the variable is not `nil`, otherwise `map` returns `nil` and the expression evaluates to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the resulting string in another string, like this:

`let string = "The value is: \(variable)"`

and possibly specify what to print when `variable` is `nil` :

`let string = "The value is: \(variable, nil: "value is nil")"`

you can write a handy generic extension for String.StringInterpolation which takes any type of value and prints this and if it's an optional and also `nil` it prints the specified "default" string:

```
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation<T>(_ value: T?, `nil` defaultValue: @autoclosure () -> String) {
        if let value = value {
            appendLiteral("\(value)")
        } else {
            appendLiteral(defaultValue())
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var d: Double? = nil
print("Double: \(d, nil: "value is nil")")

d = 1
print("Double: \(d, nil: "value is nil")")

let i = 1
print("Integer: \(i, nil: "value is nil")")
```

Output on the console:

```
Double: value is nil
Double: 1.0
Integer: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun a generic approach to cover all types that conforms to LosslessStringConvertible:

```
extension LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}
```

---

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { self?.string ?? "" }
}
```

---

```
var double = Double("2.7")

print(double.string)    // "2.7\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Property wrappers should help you give the desired result - property wrappers have a special variables ***wrappedValue*** and ***projectedValue*** that can add a layer of separation and allow you to wrap your custom logic.

**wrappedValue** - manipulate this variable with getters and setters. It has very less use in our case as it is of Double? type

**projectedValue** - this is going to be our focus as we can use this variable to project the Double as a String in our case.

The implementation is as below

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct DoubleToString {
    private var number: Double = 0.0
    var projectedValue: String = ""
    var wrappedValue: Double?{
        get {
            return number // Not really required
        }
        set {
            if let value = newValue { // Check for nil
                projectedValue = value.description // Convert to string
                number = value
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Now we create a struct which uses this wrapper.

```
struct NumbersTest {
    @DoubleToString var number1: Double?
    @DoubleToString var number2: Double?
}
```

On running the below code, we get the desired result. $number1 gives us the `projectedValue` and if we ignore the $ symbol we get the `wrappedvalue`

```
var numbersTest = NumbersTest()
numbersTest.number1 = 25.0
numbersTest.number2 = nil

print(numbersTest.$number1) //"25.0"
print(numbersTest.$number2) //""
```

By using property wrappers you can keep the variable interoperable to get both Double and String values easily.

Comment: My `Double?` is a parameter, not a property/member